# player isn't moving from its initial position in unreal engine 5

Tags: unreal-engine5

Dears

when I run the game in unreal engine 5, the player only turns left, right, up, and down, but it's not moving from its initial position, I tried quitting the app and running it again but the issue persists, below SS is from the log:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The player moves left, right, up and down but stays in its original position? Your question makes no sense at all. Are you referring to the direction it is facing? Also you need to provide some code at least.

Comment: @JulesUK the player turnes but not moves. Sorry for not providing enough information, I provided the blueprint, thank for your reply!